# It does not say that A and B is mutually inclusive, so p(AUB) is between 1/2 and 1, right?

Tags: probability

[image]

It does not say that A and B is mutually inclusive, so p(AUB) is between 1/2 and 1, right?

Comment: Yes, $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$, also $P(A\cap B)$ is at most 1/2.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what "mutually inclusive" means...do you mean "mutually exclusive"? But your conclusion is correct.  If $A=B$ the answer is $\frac 12$.  If $A=B^c$ the answer is $1$.

Answer (score 0):

As said in comments, you are correct. Since $P(A)+P(B)-P(A∩B)=P(A\cup B)$, we can calculate that $0\le P(A∩ B)\le \frac{1}{2}$, and so $P(A\cup B)$ is between $\frac{1}{2}$ and $1.$

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to answer is to do a diagram of the situation you are facing

[image]

As  you can see $P(A \cap B)$ can be between zero and 0.5 (I indicated $A \cap B$ as $AB$)

thus $0.5\leq P(A \cup B)\leq1$